# zappa handler not import django app

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I deploye aws lambda django application with help of [zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa). My project works fine locally with wsgi but when I deploy on aws lambda it raise error.

Any help?

**zappa tail**:

```
:`Calling tail for stage new2..
Warning! AWS Lambda may not be available in this AWS Region!
Warning! AWS API Gateway may not be available in this AWS Region!
[1496566100097] [INFO] 2017-06-04T08:48:20.97Z 8e08e84e-4902-11e7-9744-b7104a9a6ab2 Detected environment to be AWS Lambda. Using synchronous HTTP transport.
[1496566100160] No module named accounts: ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 484, in lambda_handler
  return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
  handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 143, in __init__
  wsgi_app_function = get_django_wsgi(self.settings.DJANGO_SETTINGS)
  File "/var/task/django_zappa_app.py", line 20, in get_django_wsgi
  return get_wsgi_application()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-dt_DVN/Django/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
  File "/tmp/pip-build-dt_DVN/Django/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
  File "/tmp/pip-build-dt_DVN/Django/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
  File "/tmp/pip-build-dt_DVN/Django/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named accounts
[1496566112758] 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

`
**My project tree:**

```
    .
├── apps
│   ├── accounts
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── filters.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│ 
├── manage.py
├── my_project
│   ├── apiv1_urls.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── partner_logging.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── conf.ini
│   │   
│   │   ├── dev.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── prod.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   └── dev.txt
└── zappa_settings.json
```

**zappa_settings.json**

```
{
"new2": {
    "aws_region": "ap-south-1",
    "django_settings": "my_project.settings",
    "profile_name": "default",
    "s3_bucket": "xyz"
}
```

}

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Same issue here. If you check your zip file, you'll probably see that the apps folder is missing. I'm still working on how to get Zappa to resolve that, so far the `include` setting isn't helping.

Answer (score 3):

My problem turned out to be that my application and my virtual environment have the same name. So if you're using `virtualenvwrapper` and your venv is called `apps` or `accounts` try making a new one with a different name.

`zappa package $ENV -o zappa.zip && unzip -vl zappa.zip` if you want to see what it's actually uploading

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#package

```
$ zappa -v
0.46.1
$ zappa package -h
usage: zappa package [-h] [--all] [-a APP_FUNCTION] [-s SETTINGS_FILE] [-q]
                     [-j] [--disable_progress] [-o OUTPUT]
                     [stage_env]

positional arguments:
  stage_env
```

Comment: Thank you, this was my case. Renaming virtualenv worked for me and I've posted the issue on GitHub https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1959